# Set property from another table with no relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to set a property in my entity based from another entity that has no relationship one to the other. The entity sets the properties from the database and I want one of the properties to be set from another table in database, but I can't get to the bottom of it.

For example,

```
public class First {
    [Key]
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSavedForLater
        {
            get
            {
                return Logs.Where(l =>
                {
                    var content = l.LogContent.JsonStringToObject<History>();
                    return (content.ProdId == ProdId && l.TableName == "Condition");
                }).Any();
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see the property IsSavedForLater is `[NotMapped]` and I want this property to get set from the Logs,

Here is the log Entity,

```
public class Log
{
    [Key]
    public int LogId { get; set; }
    public string LogContent { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public string BlameName { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to navigate like this without any database relationship?

Comment: Is it not working now? On the surface, it seems that it should. Note that EF will not map a get-only property, so the NotMapped attribute is redundant.

Comment: @EricJ. No its not working, I'm getting `invalid column First_ProdId` error, good point about NotMapped though

Comment: You might have better luck isolating the error if you actually loop through the logs instead of using Linq.

Comment: Also, as a side note, `Logs.Where(...).Any()` is redundant.  You can just use `Logs.Any(...)`

Comment: You're actually saying that `First` can't have a `Logs` collection because the foreign key doesn't exist.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes that's right, do you think its possible to achieve like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found my solution after a huge amount of time figuring it out.

What I did is, I added first another property in my First class like this

```
public class First {
    [Key]
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the First class has a new property `TableName` that is also in my Logs class like this,

```
public class Log
{
    [Key]
    public int LogId { get; set; }
    public string LogContent { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public string BlameName { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added in the db context class a model builder like this,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<SmuForecasting>().HasKey(x => new { x.TableName }).HasMany(x => x.PsLogs).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => new { x.TableName });
}
```

That worked perfectly good for me but with side effects, it replaces the original key that was set to it in the beginning, so I ended up doing a total different approach.